# How can I internationalize my REST service with Quarkus?

Tags: quarkus

When building REST services with Spring or Micronaut, I've a **MessageSource** to internationalize my responses.

But I did not find anything comparable in Quarkus. I created a REST service and want to return a message based on the user's / browsers language. How can I achieve this? Is there anything like a MessageSource?

```
public String i18n() {
   return ????.getMessage('MY_KEY', MY_LOCALE);
}
```

Am I missing something here? Has Quarkus a completely different way for this? Or is it just not possible?

Thanks for your help,
Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quarkus does not provide any out of the box support for this.

If you would like to have something similar implemented in Quarkus, please open a GitHub issue asking for the feature

Comment: Is there still no implementation ? @geoand

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Answer (score 0):

I made this work using a separate service.

My setup is:

```
main
├── java
│   └── com
│       └── foo
│             └── i18n
│                 ├── LocalizationService.java
│                 └── LocalizedMessages.java
└── resources
    ├── application.properties
    └── messages
        ├── msg_en.properties
        ├── ... more languages
        └── msg_es.properties
```

`LocalizedMessages.java` has the standard stuff documented:

```java
@MessageBundle
public interface LocalizedMessages {

    @Message
    String invalid_login_error();

}
```

Problem here is, to use this bundles as documented by quarkus, you have to do:

```java
@Localized("cs") 
LocalizedMessages msg;
```

But you don't really know the locale/language at this point, which makes it useless*

To make this work you first need the `Accept-Language` header (easy with `@Header`) and feed it to this:

```java
@RequestScoped
public class LocalizationService {
    public LocalizedMessages getLocalizedMessages(String language) {
        try {
            return MessageBundles.get(LocalizedMessages.class, Localized.Literal.of(language));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.warnf("Failed to get localization messages for language %s", language);
            return MessageBundles.get(LocalizedMessages.class);
        }
    }
}
```

You endpoint methods would look like:

```java
@Inject
LocalizationService i18n;

@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public Response login(@FormParam("email") String email, @FormParam("pwd") String pwd, @Header("Accept-Language") String language) {
    var msg = this.i18n.getLocalizedMessages(language);
    // ...
    var error = msg.invalid_login_error();
    var template = Templates.login(error);
    return Response.ok(template).build();
}
```

Comment: btw, this is for quarkus 2.x. Not sure if things change on quarkus 3.x