# How to handle internationalization (i18n) in Quarkus?

Tags: internationalization, quarkus

I would like to build a multilingual Quarkus Restful API, or GraphQL API, but i am wondering if there is a way to handle internationalization (i18n) in Quarkus for translating messages, responses?

Comment: it is not supported out of the box check https://stackoverflow.com/a/67580900/175554

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I internationalize my REST service with Quarkus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67573063/how-can-i-internationalize-my-rest-service-with-quarkus)